# neural network deciding the next output

Tags: matlab

I'd like to make a piece of music and there are 16 sounds possible, but not every sound can follow the other (for example sound 'A' can be followed by sound 'B', 'D' and 'F' but not by 'c' and 'E' etc). I have substituted this as a vector with 16 state spaces (values between 0 and 9) and I'd like to use them as inputs for neural network. Let's say I get new values as random (from 0 to 9) for the 16 elements of my vector. Now what I'd like my network to decide is which is the best suited value from the 16 based on the value of the last output, because as I already mentioned, each element has a certain number of possible elements that can come afterwards. DO YOU THINK IT COULD BE SOLVED BY NEURAL NETWORK and WHAT KIND OF NN WOULD BE BEST SUITED. Does anyone have similar examples. THANKS!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Computer generated music? What about cadence? Is that a variable? What about note groupings (quaver, semi-quaver etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a neural network, you may just want to create a table of probabilities that mark transitions between your notes. Imagining you could only play A, C, and E:

```
    A     C     E
A   0.2   0.1   0.7
C   0.4   0.2   0.4
E   0.2   0.5   0.3
```

Using that table as an example, you could start on a random note (let's say a C). Then, using the table and starting from the row for 'C', we see that with a 0.4 probability we go to A, a 0.2 probability we go to C again, and a 0.4 probability we go to E. Then you just keep transitioning between your notes. A lot simpler than a neural network, and it may be closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: I think you are referring to a Markov Chain

Comment: Yep! That's exactly what it is.

Comment: First of all thank you. It might seem that my questions are simple, but I'm self teaching myself matlab so I need some time to get my programming skills to my creative-intellectual ones. Yes, I am aware of the Markov chain theory, but I don't want to use it because I'm don't want this kind of stochastic behavior. To be exact, what I already can do to some extent is to build cellular automatons as 2 or 3D matrices. But - as sometimes the results are so crazy that it makes no musical sense, I'd like to put another fitness function in form of a Neural Network.

Comment: This is why I have made kind of a 'social network' of which sounds are connected to each other and the cellular automaton is giving me the "winner" sound, but I'd just like to check the result according to my network. So if I have 0 ='quiet' in last generation and than get 9 = 'extremely loud' and these 2 sound are not allowed to follow each other, than the 2nd best result will win. As I have already my weights generated from the cellular automaton, I don't need the probability of Markov's chain to determine my final result.